# Rails generating JSON Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I want to generate a JSON object while fetching data from database.

```
def duration
  return @data[:duration] unless @data[:duration].nil?

  @data[:duration] = per_hour.collect do | val |
    [val[0], val[1]]
  end
end
```

I get the data I need, but the array isn't correct. My view looks like:

```
var array = <%= raw @duration_data.to_json %>;
```

And my array looks like this:

```
var array = [{"data": [[0,0],[1,60.0]] }];
```

But what I need is this:

```
var array = [{"data": {"0":0, "1":60.0} }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write this as follows:

```
def duration
  @data[:duration] ||= build_duration
end
```

This is a short way to say: return `@data[:duration]` if not nil, otherwise, assign `build_duration` to it.

And then you define `build_duration`

```
def build_duration
  result = {}
  per_hour.each do |val|
    result[val[0]] = val[1]
  end
  result
end
```

You can write the `build_duration` more compact, but for me this is very readable: it will build a hash and fill it up as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to convert your array to a hash:

```
@data[:duration] = per_hour.collect do |val|
  [val[0], val[1]]
end.to_h
```

For Ruby 1.9:

```
@data[:duration] = Hash[*per_hour.collect { |val| [val[0], val[1]] }]
```

Comment: thanks, but I got this error  undefined method `to_h' for [[0, 3]]:Array

Comment: You probably have an old Ruby version, I will correct the answer

Comment: No I'm running with rails 2.1

Comment: This has nothing to do with rails, you need to check your ruby version. You can do this in your project root by typing `ruby --version` in your console

Answer (score 1):

```
@data[:duration] ||= per_hour.collect { | val | [val[0], val[1]] }.to_h
```

Try this.

Comment: I got this error: undefined method `to_h' for [[0, 3]]:Array

Comment: This should return    ```pry(main)> [[0, 3]].to_h```
```=> {0=>3}```